# Decodable, doesn't decode optional enum with invalid value

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I have defined a enum like this:

```
enum ClubLevel: Int, Codable {
    case golden = 1, silver, bronze
}
```

in my struct I have an optional property of type `ClubLevel` and when I decode this property in `init(from decoder: Decoder)`:

```
self.clubLevel = try container.decode(ClubLevel?.self, forKey: .clubLevel)
```

I face this error:

debugDescription: `"Cannot initialize ClubLevel from invalid Int value 0", underlyingError: nil"`

I'm wondering even this property is optional, decoder won't continue

any idea?

Comment: thanks for your comment @hamish can you explain whats difference between `try? container.decode(ClubLevel.self, forKey: .clubLevel)` and `try container.decode(ClubLevel?.self, forKey: .clubLevel)`. you can post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The line

```
self.clubLevel = try container.decode(ClubLevel?.self, forKey: .clubLevel)
```

doesn't try to decode `ClubLevel`, assigning `nil` if unsuccessful. What it does is:

1. Try to decode `nil` (represented in JSON as `null`) for the `clubLevel` key. If unsuccessful,
2. Try to decode a `ClubLevel` for the `clubLevel` key. If unsuccessful,
3. Throw an error

So if the value for the `clubLevel` key is neither `nil` nor a valid `ClubLevel` representation, you'll get an error thrown. You'll note that this also means you'll get an error thrown if the `clubLevel` key is missing entirely (rather than being present with a value of `nil`).

Ignoring missing keys is done with `decodeIfPresent`:

```
self.clubLevel = try container.decodeIfPresent(ClubLevel.self, forKey: .clubLevel)
```

This will now:

1. Return `nil` if the `clubLevel` key is missing from the container. If they key is present,
2. Try to decode `nil` (represented in JSON as `null`) for the `clubLevel` key. If unsuccessful,
3. Try to decode a `ClubLevel` for the `clubLevel` key. If unsuccessful,
4. Throw an error

This is the default behaviour for decoding optionals in a compiler-generated implementation of `init(from:)`. It will still throw an error in your case as the value for the `clubLevel` key is not a valid `ClubLevel`.

If you want to just try and decode a `ClubLevel`, assigning `nil` on the decoding failing for *any* reason (key missing, invalid value, etc.), then you want to use `try?`:

```
self.clubLevel = try? container.decode(ClubLevel.self, forKey: .clubLevel)
```

Comment: What if we need to assign a default value on ANY failing reason?

Comment: @Jan You’d want to use the nil coalescing operator, e.g `(try? container.decode(ClubLevel.self, forKey: .clubLevel)) ?? default`

Comment: Ahh, I was missing the parenthesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem and thought I'd add my solution for anyone interested.

The idea is to wrap the enum inside the following `struct`:

```
struct OptionalDecodableEnum<T>: Decodable where T: RawRepresentable, T.RawValue: Decodable {
    let value: T?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        value = T(rawValue: try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(T.RawValue.self))
    }
}
```

The main benefit is that you don't have to implement `Decodable` every time you want an optional enum. You also don't need the optional chaining with extra parentheses.

However, you will have to return the inner `value` property when you want to use it. E.g.

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    enum ClubLevel: Int, Codable {
        case golden = 1, silver, bronze
    }

    let clubLevel: OptionalDecodableEnum<ClubLevel>
}

let foo = try jsonDecoder.decode(Foo.self, from: data)
print(String(describing: foo.clubLevel.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a method which solves a similar problem as described in this post - just for an array of enum values instead of a single one. Since this was the first post showing up when looking for an answer to this problem I wanted to share my solution here in case it could maybe help someone with a similar problem :)

Problematic Example:

```
{
  "exampleArray": [
     "FirstExample",
     "SecondExample",
     "abcde123",
     "FourthExample"
  ]
}
```

```swift
// ...
// Usage
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    enumArray = try? container.decodeEnumArray([EnumType].self, forKey: .enumArray)
}

// ...

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {

    func decodeEnumArray<T: RawRepresentable>(_: [T].Type, forKey key: Self.Key) throws -> [T] where T.RawValue: Decodable {
        return try decode([T.RawValue].self, forKey: key).map { T(rawValue: $0) }.compactMap { $0 }
    }
}
```

enumArray will then be `[FirstExample, SecondExample, FourthExample]`